# watch do not show variable changing

Tags: vue.js

I have got array `rasters_previews_list` with data.

```
  methods: 
  { 
      removeit: function (index) 
      {
        this.rasters_previews_list.splice(index, 1)
      }

  },

 watch:
  {
    rasters_previews_list : function(oldval, newval) 
    {
      console.log("Value changed"); 
      console.log("oldval: ", oldval); 
      console.log("newval: ", newval); 

    }

  }
```

Output:

```
oldval: Object1: Object2: Object3
newval: Object1: Object2: Object3
```

old and new are same! But element was removed!

Does `splice` update array size as `Vue-delete`?

The problem that every time I am getting in console equal `oldval` and `newval`. I know that js have some limitation, and for example it's not possible traking array changing. And Vue for it use method `set`. Maybe it's same case? Or it's another issue?

Real working code: http://5.200.52.99:8080/ 
login as user. Select Europe with polygon, then try remove founded image from panel with `X` button. Chrome console will show 2 same arrays.

The task is track value-changing in app like http://vuejs.org/guide/#All-Together-Now with `watch`

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @gurghet I added link to online project.

Comment: Yeah but that link will not last forever, these questions will be read in the next months, it would be better to post long lasting links.

Comment: @gurghet I tried to put code to JSFeedle I can't get it work there. Short form of question is how to track value-changing in app like http://vuejs.org/guide/#All-Together-Now

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I've though that you're using `.slice()`. So as long as you're use splice this answer isn't valid. But I'll keep it here for the record. Also the answer contain link to documentation.

Yes, `.splice()` updates array.

---

No, `vuejs` don't track such array mutations:

According to [documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods):

> Vue.js wraps an observed Array’s mutation methods so they will also
>   trigger View updates. The wrapped methods are:
>
> - push()
> - pop()
> - shift()
> - unshift()
> - splice()
> - sort()
> - reverse()

And

> `filter()`, `concat()` and `slice()`, which do not mutate the original Array but always return **a new Array**

So the idea is to replace you array with a new one:

```
example1.items = example1.items.filter(function (item) {
  return item.message.match(/Foo/)
})
```

Comment: Can I do: `removeit: function (index) 
              {
                this.rasters_previews_list.pop(index)
              }` 
? 

I need track value changes in app like http://vuejs.org/guide/#All-Together-Now